# plone.app.caching for front page only

Tags: caching, plone

I'd like to enable content item/folder cache-in-proxy  for the site front page only (complex, heavy loading operations).

What would be good approach to "cache in only certain path" problem with plone.app.caching?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to define a new caching ruleset, and associate it with your homepage view. You can then assign the Strong or Moderate caching operation to this ruleset while leaving the other rulesets set to Weak or No caching.

The ZCML for defining the new ruleset and associating it with the homepage view would be as follows, assuming the homepage view is ".homepage.HomepageView":

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns:cache="http://namespaces.zope.org/cache"/>

  <include package="z3c.caching" file="meta.zcml" />

  <cache:rulesetType
      name="plone.homepage"
      title="Homepage"
      description="Site homepage view"
      />

  <cache:ruleset
      for=".browser.HomepageView"
      ruleset="plone.homepage"
      />

</configure>
```

(See the [z3c.caching](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.caching) documentation for more on the cache directives used here.)

If your homepage is a template in a CMF skin layer rather than a view, you can associate it with a ruleset on the "Caching operations" tab of the plone.app.caching control panel, instead of using the cache:ruleset directive.

A completely different approach would be to handle the homepage specially in your reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: We've (on occasion) associated the homepage view with the Folder cache rules; that rule suffices for most situations where the output is based on catalog information rather than information only from the current object.